# How to create MySQL Triggers through setup script

Tags: magento2, install-script, upgrade-script, setup-upgrade, mysql-triggers

I placed trigger statement in installer script but it didn't create in MySQL.

Created File here `Custom/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        //Your code for upgrade data base
         $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();


        $installer->run("CREATE TRIGGER `insert_user_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `sitealluser` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.designs_created_at = NOW();");

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: share your code, what you have tried so far

Comment: Updated code @MurtuzaZabuawala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\TriggerFactory` to create mysql triggers through setup script: (not test yet)

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\TriggerFactory
     */
    protected $triggerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\TriggerFactory $triggerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->triggerFactory = $triggerFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        //Your code for upgrade data base
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $triggerName = 'insert_user_trigger';
        $event = 'UPDATE';

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger $trigger */
        $trigger = $this->triggerFactory->create()
            ->setName($triggerName)
            ->setTime(\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger::TIME_AFTER)
            ->setEvent($event)
            ->setTable($setup->getTable('sitealluser'));

        $trigger->addStatement($this->buildStatement($event));

        $setup->getConnection()->dropTrigger($trigger->getName());
        $setup->getConnection()->createTrigger($trigger);

        $installer->endSetup();

    }


    protected function buildStatement($event, $changelog = null)
    {
        switch ($event) {
            case \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger::EVENT_INSERT:
            case \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger::EVENT_UPDATE:
                $triggerSql = "INSERT ON `sitealluser` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.designs_created_at = NOW()";
                return $triggerSql;
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }

}
```

**There is a good sample: `vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php`**.

Comment: You can use `$trigger->addStatement()` to add new statement.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and working code,

```
    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
      protected $triggerFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\TriggerFactory $triggerFactory
        )
        {
            $this->triggerFactory = $triggerFactory;
        }

        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;

            $installer->startSetup();
            $trigger = $this->triggerFactory->create()
                ->setName('after_quote_item_option_insert')
                ->setTime(\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger::TIME_BEFORE)
                ->setEvent('INSERT')
                ->setTable($setup->getTable('quote_item_option'));

            $trigger->addStatement("IF NEW.code =  'info_buyRequest' THEN SET NEW.code = CONCAT(  'info_buyRequest_', NOW( ) ) ; END IF ;");

              $setup->getConnection()->dropTrigger($trigger->getName());
              $setup->getConnection()->createTrigger($trigger);

          $installer->endSetup();
        } 
    }
```